# Pegar dados xml com php

Tags: php, xml

Nunca trabalhei com XML. Abaixo coloquei o código XML como recebo de uma URL. Gostaria de pegar os dados de latitude e longitude e passar para uma variável PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <feedMessageResponse>
        <count>10</count>
        <feed>
            <id>03XHH0sPyTiYUsYD2TVJ4q7CzEH89HBhG</id>
            <name>OneAtATime</name>
            <description>OneAtATime</description>
            <status>ACTIVE</status>
            <usage>0</usage>
            <daysRange>7</daysRange>
            <detailedMessageShown>true</detailedMessageShown>
        </feed>
        <totalCount>10</totalCount>
        <activityCount>0</activityCount>
        <messages>
            <message clientUnixTime="0">
                <id>4937065</id>
                <messengerId>0-8356068</messengerId>
                <messengerName>Spot2</messengerName>
                <unixTime>1364909292</unixTime>
                <messageType>HELP-CANCEL</messageType>
                <latitude>-99999.0</latitude>
                <longitude>-99999.0</longitude>
                <modelId>SPOT2</modelId>
                <showCustomMsg>Y</showCustomMsg>
                <dateTime>2013-04-02T06:28:12-0700</dateTime>
                <hidden>0</hidden>
                <messageContent>The help message has been cancelled</messageContent>
            </message>
            <message clientUnixTime="0">
                <id>4937064</id>
                <messengerId>0-8356068</messengerId>
                <messengerName>Spot2</messengerName>
                <unixTime>1364909283</unixTime>
                <messageType>HELP</messageType>
                <latitude>45.42249</latitude>
                <longitude>-111.68832</longitude>
                <modelId>SPOT2</modelId>
                <showCustomMsg>Y</showCustomMsg>
                <dateTime>2013-04-02T06:28:03-0700</dateTime>
                <hidden>0</hidden>
                <messageContent>This is the default HELP message. Please update.</messageContent>
            </message>
            <message clientUnixTime="0">
                <id>4937060</id>
                <messengerId>0-8356068</messengerId>
                <messengerName>Spot2</messengerName>
                <unixTime>1364908774</unixTime>
                <messageType>CUSTOM</messageType>
                <latitude>45.42249</latitude>
                <longitude>-111.68832</longitude>
                <modelId>SPOT2</modelId>
                <showCustomMsg>Y</showCustomMsg>
                <dateTime>2013-04-02T06:19:34-0700</dateTime>
                <hidden>0</hidden>
                <messageContent>This is a custom message</messageContent>
            </message>
            <message clientUnixTime="0">
                <id>4937059</id>
                <messengerId>0-8356068</messengerId>
                <messengerName>Spot2</messengerName>
                <unixTime>1364908765</unixTime>
                <messageType>OK</messageType>
                <latitude>45.42249</latitude>
                <longitude>-111.68832</longitude>
                <modelId>SPOT2</modelId>
                <showCustomMsg>Y</showCustomMsg>
                <dateTime>2013-04-02T06:19:25-0700</dateTime>
                <hidden>0</hidden>
                <messageContent>This is the default SPOT Check-in/OK message. Please update.</messageContent>
            </message>
            <message clientUnixTime="0">
                <id>4937057</id>
                <messengerId>0-8356068</messengerId>
                <messengerName>Spot2</messengerName>
                <unixTime>1364908512</unixTime>
                <messageType>TRACK</messageType>
                <latitude>45.42249</latitude>
                <longitude>-111.68832</longitude>
                <modelId>SPOT2</modelId>
                <showCustomMsg>Y</showCustomMsg>
                <dateTime>2013-04-02T06:15:12-0700</dateTime>
                <hidden>0</hidden>
            </message>
        </messages>
    </feedMessageResponse>
</response>
```

Comment: Pode começar lendo a documentação: [Manipulação de XML](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.xml.php).

Comment: Poxa meu diretor ainda não consegui entender se der para me adiantar agradeço muito

Comment: Tenta esses então: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+xml

Comment: Nada ainda blz deixa quieto obrigado ai pela força

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O formato da resposta está meio estranho, então eu tive que fazer um loop pra mostrar todas as latitudes e longitudes.

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('url-do-xml');

$i = 1;
foreach($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message as $message) {
    print_r("Latitude $i: $message->latitude\n");
    print_r("Longitude $i: $message->longitude\n\n");
    $i++;
}
```

Substitua `url-do-xml` pela url que você obtém o xml.

Caso você não consiga abrir o xml direto pelo link você pode criar um arquivo xml temporário com essa resposta e abrir ele na função [`simplexml_load_file`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

Resultado:

```
Latitude 1: -99999.0
Longitude 1: -99999.0

Latitude 2: 45.42249
Longitude 2: -111.68832

Latitude 3: 45.42249
Longitude 3: -111.68832

Latitude 4: 45.42249
Longitude 4: -111.68832

Latitude 5: 45.42249
Longitude 5: -111.68832
```

Comment: Amigao como eu poderia pegar apenas da latitude 1

Comment: @HemersonPrestes `$latitude = $xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[0]->latitude;`

Comment: Top meu amigo deu certo obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Para ler o arquivo xml:

```
$arquivo="xml.xml";//arquivo
$xml = simplexml_load_file($arquivo);/* Lê o arquivo XML e recebe um objeto com as informações */
$total = count($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message);//número de elementos

//usado com bloco array
$localizacao = array();

/* Percorre o objeto e imprime as informações na tela */
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++):

   //uma variavel com todos os elementos
   $variavel = $variavel. ($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->latitude)." ".($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->longitude)." ";

   //imprime linha a linha
   echo "Latitude: ";
   print($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->latitude);
   echo " ::: Longitude: ";
   print($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->longitude);
   echo "<br>";

   //bloco array
   $result = ($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->latitude)." ".($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->longitude);       
   //array_push() recebe dois argumentos: um array, e um elemento para adicionar no final deste array      
   array_push($localizacao, $result);
   //fim bloco array

endfor;

echo "<br>Variavel: ";
echo "<br>";
echo $variavel;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br> Array";
echo "<br>";
print_r($localizacao);
```

> Fazendo uso de variáveis dinâmicas, cada variável ($s0, $s1,$s2 ...) com uma latitude e uma longitude

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){    
   $n = "s".$i;
   $$n= ($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->latitude)." ".($xml->feedMessageResponse->messages->message[$i]->longitude);
   echo $$n;
   echo "<br>";
}
```

- SimpleXml é uma biblioteca php, que facilita a leitura de arquivos xml sem a necessidade de escrever muitos códigos.