# Configurar folha de estilo com PHP

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Estou montando um sistema administrativo e uma das opções do administrador é controlar diversas configurações de cor da página. Porem estou com dificuldades de achar a melhor forma pra colocar essas configurações no site.

Pensei em criar uma folha de estilo apenas com as configurações que o admin for modificar e colocar o código php que puxa essas informações do banco de dados, porem como fazer isso? Posso simplesmente colocar uma extensão PHP nessa folha de estilho que tudo vai funcionar?

> OBS: Estou usando Codeigniter nesse projeto.

Comment: Mano desculpa escrever em cima da sua pergunta ontem conseguiu me resolver uma situacão poderia me da só mais dica coloquei no comentário segue o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227945/pegar-dados-xml-com-php?rq=1

Comment: errei o link rsrs esse e o certo : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273834/pegar-dados-json-imprimir-php/273841#273841

Comment: Respondi lá. Da uma olhada se era isso mesmo

Comment: Perfeito mano obrigado da um ok la pra vc

Comment: Ajude a escolher a melhor resposta, vlw.

Answer (score 1):

Pode sim cara, faz um arquivo, `nome_que_quiser.php` daí você puxa o que tem que puxar nele +/- assim:

```
//arquivo.php

<?php header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8"); ?> //note <<

.container {
    width: <?php echo $user_container_width; ?>
}


//index.html
...html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="arquivo.php"/>
```

---

Já se você quiser usar `.css`, **acho** que teria de fazer algo do tipo

```
//.htaccess
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
AddHandler php5-script .css
```

---

**Edição**

Outra coisa, o problema é que esse cara(css/php) não executa junto com sua aplicação, no caso voce teria que chamar as constantes que voce quer usar arquivo por arquivo. Por exemplo o `arquivo.php` teria de fazer isso.

```
//arquivo.php
require("../constants.php");

/project
    /css
        arquivo.php
    constants.php
```

---

**Final**

Pode dar uma olhada neste [site](https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4557229.htm).

Eu já usei isso antes(.php eu falo), mas acessei esse site porque dei uma esquecida.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Tranquilo, espero que ajude a outros também.

Answer (score 0):

O mais indicado no seu caso seria utilizar SASS, pois assim você poderia atribuir as cores conforme o usuario preferir.

Você também pode simplismente salvar essas personalizações em um banco de dados e então ao carregar a página seu PHP irá dizer ao CSS qual cor deve dar aquele elemento. assim:

```
//arquivo.php

<body>
  <style>
    #elementoPersonalizado1{
      background-color: <?php echo $cor_armazenada_na_tabela;?>;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="elementoPersonalizado1">
    <p>O fundo dessa div tera a cor que esta armazenada no banco de dados</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Queria centralizar isso para não ficar repetindo código em todas as páginas.

Comment: Então coloque essa personalização em um unico arquivo e use o "require_once" para chamar para as demais páginas amigo, fácil!